# How to determine sample size prior to designing a prospective cohort study research of 2 groups?

Tags: sample-size, sample

How do I use  the a priori test to determine a sample size for my prospective cohort research that compares vaccinated males versus non vaccinated males. I am looking at the effect of vaccination on disease prevalence in the future.

Answer (score 1):

First, you will need to decide on the desired power and expected effect size in order to determine sample size. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Estimating_sample_sizes#Estimating_sample_sizes